# How can I read the input parameter of a function that is passed into another function?

Tags: dart

I am writing a method that accepts as its argument a function which also has one argument. Is it possible to access the argument of the passed-in function within the body of the method that receives the function?

---

Here's the method's syntax:
`T theMethod(T Function(T inputT) theFunction) {}`

The method (**`theMethod`**) is meant to return a `T`.

**`theMethod`** accepts as its argument a `T` function (**`theFunction`**) which takes another `T` as its argument (**`inputT`**).

I want to evaluate **`theFunction`** conditionally depending on some status of **`inputT`**.

I know I could achieve this if I pass in **`inputT`** as a separate parameter, but is there any way with the current syntax that I can access the value of **`inputT`** within the body of **`theMethod`**?

I've tried accessing **`inputT`** directly, as well as accessing it with dot-notation inside the function and neither of those seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputT` is not a variable, it's just a part of the declaration of the type of `theFunction`. When you call `theMethod`, there is no way to pass an input to `theFunction` directly without creating another parameter.